# Displaying data from DataReader in Label control (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, label, row, datareader

I have a `query` that returns one row so I want to display it in the Label, but I can't find the property `DataSource` on it.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a SqlDataReader in C# then you want something like this

```
string label;
if (reader.Read())
{
  label = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Column"))
    ? String.Empty
    : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Column"));
}
reader.Close();
MyLabel.Text = label;
```

In VisualBasic.Net it will be something like

```
Dim label as String
If reader.HasRows Then
  Label = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ColumnName"))
End If
reader.Close
MyLabel.Text = label
```

Comment: It's not working for me because I'm using it with Visual Basic

Answer (score 2):

If you are only returning one row with one column you might want to use [command.ExecuteScalar()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) instead of a data reader.  Then you can just set your label like this:

```
lblAnswer.Text = myCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old thread, but the above did not work for me. But this did:

```
 If reader.HasRows Then
       label = reader("columnName")
       labelName.Text = label
 End If
```

smc